# DFRobot LCD shield minimum pin connections

Tags: arduino, lcd

I am connecting a DFRobot LCD shield (http://www.dfrobot.com/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=51#.UYWE0itxsVk) to a bareduino.  There will be no shield placed on top of the LCD and am looking to minimally connect it to the bareduino.

What I believe must be connected:

- D4-D10
- A0
- 5V
- GND

Candidates for not being connected:

- Reset
- A1-A5
- D0-D3, D11-D13
- AREF
- 2 GNDS
- 3.3V
- VIN

What pins must be connected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you want, just the lcd or the complete functionality of the shield   (lcd + buttons).

If you just want the lcd:
D4-D10
5V
GND

If you want the lcd + buttons:
D4-D10
A0
5V
GND

It is explained clearly in the manual: ( @ pin allocation)
http://www.dfrobot.com/wiki/index.php?title=Arduino_LCD_KeyPad_Shield_(SKU:_DFR0009)

The rest of the pins are there for other shields to stack below / above it.

**Edit:**
Here are the schematics:
http://www.dfrobot.com/image/data/DFR0009/LCDKeypad%20Shield%20V1.0%20SCH.pdf

It uses 5V because the VCC pin on the schematic matches the +5V pin on the [arduino Uno](http://www.adafruit.com/adablog/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/ArduinoUno_R3_Pinouts_600.png)

In the schematic you can also see that the other pins are not used.

Comment: Where in the pin allocation does it list 5V or GND?  Do all grounds need to be connected?  How are you sure 3.3V or AHREF aren't used?

Comment: If you open the schematics you can see they do nothing. Ahref is the analog reference pin of the arduino and in the schematic it connects to nothing. It is 5 V because the vcc connector in the schematic matches the +5V pin of the arduino Uno.